# Is G-Wan web server already dead?

Tags: release, g-wan

We are using this server for almost a year now.

Last forum post seen in November, 2011.
Last server version released 28/03/12.

Just wondering if anyone knows whats happening inside the company?
Should we expect something or should we start looking for alternatives?

Comment: Send *them* an e-mail. In any case, Off-Topic here on SO.

Comment: G-WAN added support for C# scripts in September, for Scala in October and 10 more languages since then (Javascript, PHP, Ruby, Lua, Perl, Python, Go, etc.). It does not look so dead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did what you did not do: using email to ask the question to the people able to answer.

And they replied that:

- the forum was closed because they could not cope with the amount of accounts created daily to publish junk
- the next version will be the most important ever made for G-Wan, with new features like a caching reverse proxy and an elastic load-balancer as well as system replacements like a wait-free memory allocator.

With regard to such developments, a 3-month period without publishing releases sounds reasonable.

More reasonable than assuming that such an 'inactivity period' means that *"the project is dead"*.

Would you say that for other Web servers like Apache which have much larger release cycles?

Answer (score 0):

You should always be expecting something from G-WAN.  It's a great piece of software. Here's the other thing too: G-WAN was expertly engineered.  That doesn't mean that there are no bugs in it, or that features can't be implemented, but G-WAN is incredibly tight.

It has lean code, it does what it supposed to do, very well, and it is built for the developer to add in the functionality that hasn't been put in there yet.

That's the beauty of it, or one facet of the beauty.

Comment: Tim, why are you commenting on the code which I will dare assume you have never seen? G-Wan is not open source, where do you draw the conclusion its code is lean and it is expertly engineered? I am noticing the only people praising G-Wan on SO are people who only talk about G-Wan. Check for yourself. If something sounds too good to be true, it probably is. And yes, I have seen the benchmark pages across the Internet.

Comment: It's pretty simple.. G-WAN has an incredibly small footprint. I've checked my system resources when it's running.  It also does what it says it can.  I'm currently using it to do in REAL TIME what was taking 1-1.5 seconds with other web application servers.  Also, please look at my posts too.  I "praise G-WAN", yet I think there may be like 5 TOTAL posts that I have on that.  All the rest are PHP or JavaScript related.

Comment: Ok, Tim, I have no gripes with that. But we programmers welcome accuracy, and saying "it has lean code" without having seen the code doesn't do justice to your reputation, admit it. Just because the tool is fast and impresses you, doesn't mean its code is "lean". For all we know it could be hand-tailored to [undocumented features of] the Linux kernel, and it will blow in our face when the company goes down under and we will supposedly decrypt the code with the decryption keys we have.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused... wouldn't have a small package size relate to having "lean code"?  Moreover, I've spoken with the engineers at TrustLeap, and the response given was essentially: "G-WAN will adapt to the environment that allows it to work best."  So, for the Windows version of G-WAN, development was stopped because of issues with the OS. Currently Linux is the main OS, however if BSD were to prove a better environment, then G-WAN would adapt itself to that. I don't see anything wrong with that type of behavior. It's utilizing the resources available, is that unprofessional?

Comment: (Also, please read that comment as a genuine question, which it is)

Comment: from TFD.com: lean: 1. Not fleshy or fat; thin. Tim++